# Loop invariant Hoare Logic

Tags: proof-of-correctness, hoare-logic

I have a program, where I should find a loop invariant and then provide a proof.

```
      {x>=0 && y>=0} // precondition
res:=0;
i:=0;
while (i<y) do
res:=res+x;
i:=i+1;
od
      {res:=x*y} //postcondition
```

The only logical loop invariant for me is `res<=x*y`, which is straightforward from postcondition, but I dont think that it the best one to go on with. Maybe any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
{x>=0 && y>=0} // precondition
res:=0;
i:=0;
while (i<y) do
    {res=x*i} // invariant
    res:=res+x;
    i:=i+1;
    {res=x*i} // invariant
end
{res=x*y} //postcondition
```

By these conditions you should be able to show both that the program is partially correct (i.e. if the loop terminates, the answer is correct) and that it terminates. Although I suppose you need the precondition that y is an integer, too.

Comment: Thanks, but why you mentioned it twice? I mean it is for sure that it should hold true both at the beginning and at the end. And, I logically got how to show that it is partially correct but what about fully? Can you give a hint on that?

Comment: I mentioned it twice to make sure that the operations within the loop's body preserve the invariant ([... an invariant of a loop is a property that holds before (and after) each repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant)). As for total correctness, you have that total correctness is the same as partial correctness + the loop terminating.